# How can I organize this logic

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

Help me please!!

I want to create editable data table. In top of the table will be a button "Add" that adds row to the table with javascript. And in each row should be butons(links) "Save" and "Delete".

How can i send post request to server?

SORRY FOR MY dullness..

In application.js I have a function like this

```
function AddElementsToPage(elements) {
/*elements - is array with name elements whose will be add to page*/    
this.add_row_to_data_table = function(obj,attributes,selector_table){
    last_row_of_table = selector_table.find('tbody tr').last();
    var new_row = "<tr><th scope='row'></th>";

    if ($.isEmptyObject(last_row_of_table.html()))
    {
        $.each(attributes, function(index, item){
            input_tag = "<input id=\""+obj+"_"+item+"\" name=\""+obj+"["+item+"]\" size=\"10\"  type=\"text\" />";
            new_row = new_row + "<td>"+input_tag+"</td>";
        })
        alert(new_row);
        selector_table.append(new_row+"</tr>");
    }else
    {
        alert("not empty");
    }

}
```

my controllers action  new

```
def new
 @table_row = SchOfWorkInformation.new
respond_to do |format|
  format.js do
    render :action => 'new'
  end
end
end
```

My new.js file

```
var obj = new AddElementsToPage();

obj.add_row_to_data_table("sch_of_working",["date","hour"], $('.data_table'))
```

My index.haml

```
 = link_to content_tag('span', "Add" , :class=>"add"),   new_sch_of_work_information_path, :remote => true
 %table{:border=>"1", :class=>"data_table", :style=>"width:450px"}
    %thead
      %th{:style=>"width:5%;"} №
      %th{:style=>"width:10%;"} Date
      %th{:style=>"width:10%;text-align:center;"} schedule_code
      %th{:style=>"width:2%;",:class=>"transperent_right_border"} 
      %th{:style=>"width:2%;"} 
    %tbody
      %tr
        %th{:scope=>"row"}
        %td=@sch.date
        %td=@sch.schedule_code
        %td{:style=>"text-align:center"}= link_tag "save", sch_of_work_informations, #how can send post request in here 
        %td{:style=>"text-align:center"}
```

Comment: This is a very general question. Please post some code, show us what you've tried, and ask something specific.

Comment: Utkanos, i want to create editable data table. When i click a button Add on the top of the table, it should be add row with input tag. And this row should be contane a button save(or link). I don't now how to organize this

Comment: But you've not posted any code or showed us what you're working on. You're effectively asking for an entire solution, and that's not what SO is about. Show us what you've tried and if you need help with something SPECIFIC, we can help with that.

Comment: Also nothing in your question justifies either ruby or Ajax tags

Comment: I concretize my question, answer please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the kind of answer you would be looking at. Follow the tutorial from railscasts http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1 nested form and it should help you. Basically you would have an add row button and it would add in javascript the html row, you could even have a remove the row button. Once this is done just press the save button of the form to allow all change to be done.